# @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-roo

Is there anything similar for mongoDB? @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)

```
@NotNull
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateTimeFormat(style = "M-")
private Date lastUpdateDate;
```

I am trying to create a field that will automatically update the "lastUpdateDate" whenever the the document is updated.

OR

In spring roo

> field date --fieldName lastUpdateDate --type java.util.Date --notNull --persistenceType JPA_TIMESTAMP

Comment: Could you provide more information about your project? Are you using SpringData for Mongo?

Comment: I would love to see something like a PrePersist and PreUpdate annotation to handle these in Spring Data, like they have in the JPA stuff.  It doesn't seem like it would be that hard to implement, but I don't think they have it.

Comment: @David Welch - Yes, i am using SpringData for mongo.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is ' create a field that will automatically update the "lastUpdateDate" ', then you can use the annotations: @LastModifiedDate and @EnableMongoAuditing.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class Application {...}

public class ModelClass implements Persistable<String> {
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastModifiedDate;
    ...
}
```

based on:
http://www.aichengxu.com/java/2261025.htm

Answer (score 0):

Looking around I'm surprised to see that there's not a good generic solution for this kind of thing. Like @CodeChimp said, it shouldn't be hard to provide this kind of thing out of the box.

One possible solution could be creating an annotation to tag your models with and then using AOP, but that'd take a little work. [This article](http://billcomer.blogspot.com/2011/07/auditing-using-aop-and-annotations-in.html) shows a somewhat naive approach to doing something like that. I copied the code to [a gist](https://gist.github.com/dwelch2344/5008069) to give it a quick look, and it seems like it could easily be modified for what you're looking to do.

I'll try to circle back this weekend and put together an actual example, but you may want to take a look to see if you're comfortable with that kind of solution and interested.

Comment: thanks David, i am quite new to springframe work, will read more about it but if you have any actual example that would be great :)